# Hosting WCF service as Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, self-hosting

I have manage to move my complexed WCF service into a Windows Service. The binding looks like this :

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyAppClientService.CustomValidator_Behavior" name="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppClientService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpRegular" address="Regular" bindingNamespace="http://MyApp.ServiceContracts/2007/11" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService"/>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpWindowMessageSecurity" address="Windows" bindingNamespace="http://MyApp.ServiceContracts/2007/11" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyAppService/Client"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8002/MyAppService/Client"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

When the service is started I browse : `http://localhost:8002/MyAppService/Client` This works fine and I can also see the WSDL.

But when I try to connect to the service with my Winform client It cant find the service, this is how the address looks like in the client :

```
<client>
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyAppService/Client/MyAppClientService.svc/Regular" behaviorConfiguration="BasicBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyAppClientServiceRegular" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService" name="MyTest_RegularLogin"/>
</client>
```

When browsing `http://localhost:8001/MyAppService/Client` I will get a missing page, I suppose that this is right because it is hosted on tcp and not http?

When the service was hosted in the IIS7(WAS) this was working just fine but then I used a endpoint at the client that looked like this :

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/MyAppDev/MyAppClientService.svc/Regular" behaviorConfiguration="BasicBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyAppClientServiceRegular" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService" name="MyApp_RegularLogin"/>
```

Note : Regular stats that this is a regular login where the client provides username and password(no Windows login)

**Edit :**

I have followed this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

And this is how windows service class looks like

```
public class MyAppWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost _serviceHost = null;
        public MyAppWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "MyAppWindowsService";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new MyAppWindowsService());
        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (_serviceHost != null)
            {
                _serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppClientService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            _serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (_serviceHost != null)
            {
                _serviceHost.Close();
                _serviceHost = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding "mex" endpoint for metadata exchange?

Comment: Can you also show your code where you instantiate the service?

Comment: @Nightwish91 : Im not sure why I would need the mex? in this case the client do not use a proxy but a channelFactory. It did work fin in IIS7 without the mex?

Comment: Ok, just running through the instructions now.

Comment: @SnowJim - I am using service discovery myself, but I can tell you that at least the code you posted for the service class looks almost identical to what I use with success.

Comment: @Jeremy White : I found the problem, see my Answer. Now I will only have to figure out how to host multiple WCF services in one Windows Service.

Comment: The instructions are not entirely correct, no mention that you need to change your output directory to bin rather than bin/debug....

Comment: The instructions do create a working service, if you have not managed to connect your winform to the service then the form is where the problem lies, would need to see your form to attempt to help with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to connect to `localhost/MyAppDev/MyAppClientService.svc/Regular` but it whould be `localhost/MyAppDev/Regular`

Comment: Good job, mark your answer resolved so others don't fall into the same trap:)

Comment: Thanks, But it can not be marked by me until 2 days from now.